# PDF To Excel Conversion Macro

Tags: excel, pdf

I have a vba code which copies the data from a pdf file and paste it in cell A1 of the macro workbook. The code is working perfectly fine. However, this code only converts 1 file each time.

Is there a way to loop though the PDF file in a folder and copy all data from all the pdf files into the Workbook Sheet1, Cell A1.

Link to the file.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xe95FroDuPKwRgfCThnI69DvAsPB6RIX/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=102503243221897020588&rtpof=true&sd=true

```
Sub PDF2Excel()
Dim pathPDF As String, textPDF As String
Dim openPDF As Object
Dim pathCell As Range, fileCell As Range
Dim objPDF As MsForms.DataObject
Dim textArray() As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Set objPDF = New MsForms.DataObject
Set pathCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 19)
Set fileCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 19)
pathPDF = pathCell & fileCell
i = InStrRev(pathPDF, ".pdf")
If i = 0 Then
    pathPDF = pathPDF & ".pdf"
End If
If Dir(pathPDF) = "" Then
    MsgBox "The filename you provided could not be found!"
Else
    Set openPDF = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    openPDF.Open (pathPDF)
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")
    SendKeys "^a"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")
    SendKeys "^c"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:1")
End If
AppActivate ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
SendKeys "^v"
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Loop through the cells with the path and file name?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Yes, Loop though the PDF files in the folder and copy all data into marco workbook Sheet1 Cell A1. Link to the file. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xe95FroDuPKwRgfCThnI69DvAsPB6RIX/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=102503243221897020588&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Lots of looping questions on here with code. Worth checking.